# Detect if site is opened from Chrome Web Store?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way, like with JavaScript, to detect if one's site/ app is opened as part of the Google Chrome Web Store? The document.referrer 'chrome.google.com' only arrives in some limited ways of opening the app, but not always.

Apologies if this question is out of scope for StackOverflow as it's very much related to Chrome Web Store details. Thanks!

Comment: When I've needed this info in the past I'd simply add something to the URL string that I provided them with e.g. `http://myChromeApp.com?from=chromeStore` then obviously you can monitor that

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was a next step we were contemplating (perhaps even #foo if they allow that).